# How to investigate reasons for failed writes to Proficy Historian 4.5

Tags: historian, proficy

I have about 25000 failed writes within each 30 minutes. Previously I had an issue with timestamps ahead of current server clock, but this was addressed. When looking at collected data, it is OK - no gaps all values are good.

Is there any way I can tell why those writes fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the log files. For version 4.5 it should be in deafult path "C:\Proficy Historian Data\LogFiles"

Comment: I did, but there is usual stuff about creating archives and such. But I think it might be good idea to enable debug mode and then check it again.